# error on installing curl in ubuntu 16

Tags: command-line

$  sudo apt install curl

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 139 kB of archives.
After this operation, 339 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13
  500  Internal Server Error
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb  500  Internal Server Error

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you follow the advice from the error message ? `maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: The server had an '*internal error*' so I would wait awhile and try again.  If it occurs again I'd likely `sudo apt-get -f install` as it suggests but I suspect your issue relates to the server being overloaded or something that was temporary.  (Ubuntu major releases are *yy.mm* in format, though for specialized releases such as Ubuntu Core which is *yy* in format)

Comment: maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?  i have  tried this and this also sudo apt-get -f install but same issue is repeating @pLumo